# Why is it 'for I knew' not 'for I know'?

Tags: idioms

> "Snape was trying to save me?" 
>       "Of course," said Quirrell coolly. "Why do you think he wanted to referee your next match? He was trying to make sure I didn't do it again. Funny, really... he needn't have bothered. I couldn't do anything with Dumbledore watching. All the other teachers thought Snape was trying to stop Gryffindor from winning, he did make himself unpopular... and what a waste of time, when after all that, I'm going to kill you tonight."
>   Quirrell snapped his fingers. Ropes sprang out of thin air and wrapped themselves tightly around Harry.
>   "You're too nosy to live, Potter. Scurrying around the school on Halloween like that, **for all I knew you'd seen me coming to look at what was guarding the Stone**."
>   "You let the troll in?"
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Judging by [this answer of StoneyB's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92207/what-is-the-correct-definition-and-usage-of-for-all-i-know), the clause seems to say Quirrell didn’t know whether Harry had seen him on Halloween and it wasn’t important to him *at the time*, rather than *now*. Is it for this reason that he uses the past tense instead of ‘for all I know’?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right. He says "For all I knew" because he's relating what his feelings were at the time Harry was scurrying round the school on Hallowe'en, not what his feelings are now.